# How to remove the focused entry from a Combobox with the DEL or BACKSPACE key?

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, extjs4.2

I have a `Combobox` that is connected to a `Store` with a `LocalStorage Proxy`.
I am storing the search criteria that is entered in the `Combobox TextField` on `Enter` into the `Store`.

Now I want to be able to detect a `KeyDown` when the `Combobox` is `Expanded` and an `Item` is highlighted with the `Cursor Keys` but not selected yet, so the user can press `DELETE` and remove that item from the `Store` and thus from the list.

I have been able to capture the `KeyDown` event with the following code, but on inspection of the API Docs and the Object in the Chrome debug console, I can't figure out how to get a reference to what is highlighted in the `Expanded` dropdown so I can remove it from the `Store`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use any selection cause at this time there is nothing selected (unless you open a combo picker where the combo has already a value set) The following example work and should show you the trick how it can be done [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a7bAY/):

```
// The data store containing the list of states
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
    data : [
        {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
        {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
        {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"}
        //...
    ]
});

// Create the combo box, attached to the states data store
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
    store: states,
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'abbr',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    listeners: {
        boxready: function(self) {
            self.createPicker().on({
                itemmouseenter: function(v,rec){self.hoveredRecord = rec},
                itemmouseleave: function(v,rec){if(self.hoveredRecord == rec) self.hoveredRecord = null; }
            })  
        },
        specialkey: function(self, e, opt) {
            if ( e.getKey() == e.ESC ) {
                self.store.remove(self.hoveredRecord);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Please note that this example only covers the `ESC` key and that the default behavior of the combo is to close the picker on that keypress (you may override it to stay open)

What it does:

Due to the fact that nothing is selected the selectionmodel of the picker wont help us much here, we need to know which item (rec) is currently 'active'. Now the picker is a boundlist and has all the events we need. I decided to go with `itemmouseenter` and `itemmouseleave` because we will get the record here. The rest is quite simple; I store a record reference on the combobox each time the mouse enter a item and remove it as soon as we leave. Now I catch the ESC event on the combo, take the record and remove it.

Comment: I was digging through and found the `Picker` but could not figure out how to get access to it, this does the trick!